# ExtJS5: Get rid of root property in proxy

Tags: rest, extjs, extjs5

I'm trying to connect a REST API to my ExtJS application.

For `GET /user` alike requests I return a response as follows:

```
{items: [{id: 1, ...}, {id: 2, ....}], total: 2}
```

So I created a model for that:

```
Ext.define('model.User', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        { name: 'id', type: 'int' },
        { name: 'name' },
    ],

    proxy: {
        reader: {
            type:          'json',
            totalProperty: 'total',
            rootProperty:  'items'
        },
        type:   'rest',
        url:    '/Api/User',
    }
});
```

The grids load data and all look perfect. Now I want to be able to request a single record which my api serves as `{id: 1, ...}`.
But when I do `model.User.load(1)` the success handler is never triggered because the response doesn't contain `items` property. If I put my record in that property, it will work but also will look ugly for other API users.

How can I make it work without the root property? I can't find any events for proxy/reader on a model to change it dynamically.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `rootProperty` can also be a function, so you could do something like:

```
rootProperty: function(raw) {
    return raw.items ? raw.items : raw;
}
```