# Extjs 6 Tree store- How to handle json that has different name for children node.

Tags: extjs, extjs5, extjs6

I'm trying to display data using  extjs 6 tree. I'm following MVVM approach. 
However my json data has other name for children node. How can I properly map this to make it work.

> { success:true,
>   data:[{ text:'Asia',places:
>            [{text:'India'}{text:'China'}]},         {text:'Europe',places:[{text:'Germany'}]}]}

here instead of children I have places. Can I make this work using any extjs  settings. Need help.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26824808/extjs5-get-rid-of-root-property-in-proxy/26824981#26824981

Comment: That did not work

Comment: What do you mean "that did not work"? How did you implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a function for the 'rootProperty' setting, as mentioned by Evan Trimboli above, and as seen in https://stackoverflow.com/a/26824981/1467976.

You need to return *either* `data` (for your first "root" record) or `places` (for subsequent records).

Something like this:

```
rootProperty: function(raw) {
  return raw.data ? raw.data : raw.places;
}
```

Okay, this isn't *exactly* the answer that Evan pointed you at, but it's pretty darn close.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Greatly appreciate it. -Extjs Noob.